# Calling data from search bar to chart.js graph in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I want to create a bar chart of chart.js in Angular 9. The user is supposed to enter a string into a search bar, which finds the respective entry in a .json file and returns its properties into the bar chart. For example, you could enter "bell pepper" and it would show a chart where one bar is named "sweet" and it's 3 high, then a bar called "sour" that's 1 high. The search component works, I can enter a name and it returns the values as text. However, I can't get it to return a proper chart.

I'm sorry if this is a basic question for you guys, I'm just an amateur learning how to code. I looked the problem up everywhere but couldn't find this problem or any way to solve it.

This is the home-page.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../data.service';
import { Post } from '../../post';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-page',
  templateUrl: './home-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-page.component.css']
})
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {

  post: Post[]
  constructor(
    public dataService: DataService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => {
      this.post = posts
      this.dataService.postsData = posts
    });
  }

  onSelectedFilter(e) {
    this.getFilteredExpenseList();

    let postname = this.post.name;
    let postsour = this.post.sour;
    let postsweet = this.post.sweet;

    this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: postname,
        datasets: [
          {
            data: postsour,
            borderColor: "#3cba9f",
            fill: false
          },
          {
            data: postsweet,
            borderColor: "#ffcc00",
            fill: false
          },
        ]
      },
      options: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            display: true
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            display: true
          }],
        }
      }
    });

  }

  getFilteredExpenseList() {
    if (this.dataService.searchOption.length > 0)
      this.post = this.dataService.filteredListOptions();
    else {
      this.post = this.dataService.filteredListOptions();
    }

  }

}
```

This is the search-bar.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { DataService } from '../../data.service';
import { Post } from '../../post';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-search-bar',
    templateUrl: './search-bar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./search-bar.component.css']
})
export class SearchBarComponent implements OnInit {

    myControl = new FormControl();
    filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;
    allPosts: Post[];
    autoCompleteList: any[]

    @ViewChild('autocompleteInput') autocompleteInput: ElementRef;
    @Output() onSelectedOption = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(
        public dataService: DataService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        // get all the post
        this.dataService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => {
            this.allPosts = posts

        });

        // when user types something in input, the value changes will come through this
        this.myControl.valueChanges.subscribe(userInput => {
            this.autoCompleteExpenseList(userInput);
        })
    }

    private autoCompleteExpenseList(input) {
        let categoryList = this.filterCategoryList(input)
        this.autoCompleteList = categoryList;
    }

    // this is where filtering the data happens according to you typed value
    filterCategoryList(val) {
        var categoryList = []
        if (typeof val != "string") {
            return [];
        }
        if (val === '' || val === null) {
            return [];
        }
        return val ? this.allPosts.filter(s => s.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1)
            : this.allPosts;
    }

    // after you clicked an autosuggest option, this function will show the field you want to show in input
    displayFn(post: Post) {
        let k = post ? post.name : post;
        return k;
    }

    filterPostList(event) {
        var posts = event.source.value;
        if (!posts) {
            this.dataService.searchOption = []
        }
        else {

            this.dataService.searchOption.push(posts);
            this.onSelectedOption.emit(this.dataService.searchOption)
        }
        this.focusOnPlaceInput();
    }

    removeOption(option) {

        let index = this.dataService.searchOption.indexOf(option);
        if (index >= 0)
            this.dataService.searchOption.splice(index, 1);
        this.focusOnPlaceInput();

        this.onSelectedOption.emit(this.dataService.searchOption)
    }

    // focus the input field and remove any unwanted text.
    focusOnPlaceInput() {
        this.autocompleteInput.nativeElement.focus();
        this.autocompleteInput.nativeElement.value = '';
    }


}
```

This is the post.ts that is referred to:

```
export interface Post {
    name: string,
    type: string,
    sweet: number,
    sour: number,
    salty: number,
    bitter: number,
    fatty: number,
    umami: number,
    spicy: number,
}
```

and here is a sample from the .json file:

```
[
  {
    "name": "bell pepper",
    "type": "vegetable",
    "sweet": 3,
    "sour": 1,
    "salty": 1,
    "bitter": 2,
    "fatty": 0,
    "umami": 0,
    "spicy": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "salt",
    "type": "spice",
    "sweet": 0,
    "sour": 0,
    "salty": 10,
    "bitter": 0,
    "fatty": 0,
    "umami": 0,
    "spicy": 0
  },
  {
    "name": "beef",
    "type": "meat",
    "sweet": 1,
    "sour": 0,
    "salty": 2,
    "bitter": 0,
    "fatty": 4,
    "umami": 5,
    "spicy": 0
  },
  {
    "name": "Apple",
    "type": "fruit",
    "sweet": 6,
    "sour": 3,
    "salty": 0,
    "bitter": 0,
    "fatty": 0,
    "umami": 0,
    "spicy": 0
  }
]
```

and here is the data service:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Post } from './post';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  searchOption = []
  public postsData: Post[]
  postUrl: string = "../assets/posts.json";


  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }


  getPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.http.get<Post[]>("../assets/flavors.json");

  }

  filteredListOptions() {
    let posts = this.postsData;
    let filteredPostsList = [];
    for (let post of posts) {
      for (let options of this.searchOption) {
        if (options.name === post.name) {
          filteredPostsList.push(post);
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(filteredPostsList);
    return filteredPostsList;
  }
}
```

Again, I'm very grateful for you help here. This is the first time I use Angular, and I'm at the end of my rope here. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) e.g. as [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: Could you please also post the data service? A [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) would be nice to have.

Comment: @MichaelD posted the data service... will try to get a stackblitz working but the site bugs out for me for some reason!

Comment: When you do `let postname = this.post.name;` and other local arrays, they aren't working as expected. `this.post` is an array. What you actually need is `let postname = this.post.map(p => p.name)` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In home-page component, `this.post` refers to an array of objects. To generate arrays from array of objects, use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Try the following

home-page.component.ts:

```js
let postname = this.post.map(p => p.name);
let postsour = this.post.map(p => p.sour);
let postsweet = this.post.map(p => p.sweet);
```

Working example: [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=50&ssc=43&pln=48&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBADiaEYF4YG0CwAoGMDeOeeARGAIYC2ApiQFwwkBG1ANq-NXHNQE4kAaIsRJQAnj3qMAbtQDm1KOSataQ3CIgB3aoqkBmdcUYQQAV34MAjEc3lW4qTeGkmASyhQ%20UgEy3SAGbknmJSAAz%20jGaUVG7hkSQQcG7AoQw%20wgC%20toQapBQ0Uon2UIIujOKSDInJwGrliTp6DBENphbxbSVpMFateYzunt4tCUEhnQMk0bGTxjUpPWFZOQ0FtNUs1AFlU5UbjDTBu-PauqXWCe2WMP2n3b4JQ143dyLjjgwALAkzlHEMACsV1qSxWwly83WRQAgtxVCcRPsigFeGYPIjSGdmjAAGxXcw3QxdBxLJ4eF5zd7BT63X4xf5UrGg8JZHAAXQA3DgcKBILAENB1qh4IgoBAAHQxOAACjgqAAfPAJesAJTc7B86CipCEkWC8VS8iy%20UoJVwCXXdW88Dag3Y2Boe1Gk2K5UO63YG2QECqCWsEByOVitUarW%206j%20wPB3UWT3hv0BoP2ppQT1AA)

I've created a crude [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uud2d8) for your code here. Naturally since I didn't have access to the component templates, I've bound the chart generation to a button element. Feel free to modify it to your requirements.

Comment: You are amazing! This solved my problem. Thank you especially for creating a stackblitz - I would like to modify that for future reference!

Comment: I also upvoted your answer but unfortunately do not have enough reputation yet for it to count.